Why does Tomcat 10 seem to unpack the war file incorrectly?
I'm running Tomcat 10 with Jakarta jar files. My WAR file looks like this:
tar -tf wf.war
WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/web.xml
WEB-INF/lib/
WEB-INF/lib/libHistory.jar

I copy it to the Tomcat webapps directory and the default manager unpacks it to a new directory wf which looks like this
META-INF
grp/

where grp is the start of the History.class package name. It is dropping the web.xml file and unpacking the jar to outside the WEB-INF/classes directory. The servlet starts, but when I go to the site it returns 404 with message
The requested resource [/wf/history] is not available

If I manually create webapps/wf and unpack the war file so everything looks like this:
WEB-INF/lib/libHistory.jar
WEB-INF/web.xml

It works just fine. I'm sure its something I'm missing, but I can't figure out why:

It is unpacking the jar file
Why it is unpacking it to a seemingly incorrect location.
Why is is dropping the web.xml file.

